# Delegates and VisualStudio IDE

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, delegates

I have the following code on a control of my own:

```
MethodInvoker _mi;
public MethodInvoker MI { get { return _mi; } set { _mi = value; } }
```

I thought the IDE would recognize this delegate, and allow me to choose a suitable already implemented function or create a new one if I wanted, just like it does to events, although at least at first glance, that does not seem to be the case. Is there a way to set a function to a delegate through the IDE?

Comment: I can't think of any case when to use a non-event delegate as event.

Answer (score 1):

no there is not, use event if you want to use that feature

Comment: Exactly, this is misusing a plain delegate.

Comment: Why? Events can't return values.

Comment: You know that when exposing Delegates in any way, you can use += and  -=, you just can't control the add and event. Magic...

Comment: I don't understand why it invalidates what I am saying. You can do _mi = something, so you should also be able to set a suitable delegate through the IDE.